# Add to cart button is not working magento 1.9.2, after reload the page, product are showing already added.

Tags: addtocart, magento-1.9.2.1, ajaxaddtocart

Hello Everyone I hve a running store based on magento 1.9.2.1 Everuything was fine till yesterday. But today I ma shocked to see  that After click on add to cart button only ajaz loader gif is showing moving bit product didn't get added in minicart. But when I refreshed the page minicart is showing the product are already added in this.

Nothing find rediculous in system.log and exception.log
my web url is -

> https://www.berkowits.in

If anyone can help me in this please.